# MySQL "LOCK TABLES" timeout?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, innodb

What's the timeout for mysql LOCK TABLES statement?

Can't find it anywhere.

I tried to set variable innodb_lock_wait_timeout ini my.cnf but it seems it's related to another (row level) locking not to table locking.

Simply it has no effect for LOCK TABLES.

I want to set some low timeout value for case of deadlock, because if some operation will LOCK tables and something will go wrong, it will hang up the whole site!

Which is stupid for example in case of finishing purchase on your site.

Comment: Seems like LOCK TABLES don't have any timeout and query will just hang until the lock is released.

Comment: yes i am afraid of this too. that's stupid.. as for the logic, the table locking does exactly what i need, but i am afraid of deadlock, so i will have to leave this solution. instead of it, i will make INSERT IGNORE with unique column i needed to generate in LOCK (number of invoice), and if it fails, (eg when there will be two concurrent transactions at same moment), i will try generate the invoice number again. (it should work, but only one problem is, if the first transaction will rollback, there will be hole in invoice numbers.

Comment: (while in case of LOCKing tables, this could not happen, since second concurrent transaction would wait till finish of first transaction - and doesnt matter if finish is commit, or rollback) anyway, thank you for reply. cheers

Answer (score 2):

My work-around is to create a dedicated lock table and just lock a row in that table. This has the advantage of only locking the processes that specifically want to be locked. Other parts of the application can continue to access the tables even if they are at some point touched by the update processes.

*Setup*

```
CREATE TABLE `mutex` (
    EMPTY ENUM('') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EMPTY)
);
```

*Usage*

```
set innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1;
start transaction;
insert into `mutex` values();

[... do the real work here ... or somewhere else ... even a different machine ...]

delete from `mutex`;
commit;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is the [`lock_wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lock_wait_timeout) system variable.

From the documentation:

> This variable specifies the timeout in seconds for attempts to acquire
>   metadata locks. The permissible values range from 1 to 31536000 (1
>   year). The default is 31536000.
>
> This timeout applies to all statements that use metadata locks. These
>   include DML and DDL operations on tables, views, stored procedures,
>   and stored functions, as well as LOCK TABLES, FLUSH TABLES WITH READ
>   LOCK, and HANDLER statements.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `LOCK TABLES`?

If you are using MyISAM (which sometimes needs `LOCK TABLES`), you should convert to InnoDB.

If you are using InnoDB, you should never use `LOCK TABLES`.  Instead, depend on `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` (default is an unreasonably high 50 seconds).  And you should check for errors.

InnoDB Deadlocks are caught and immediately cause an error.  Certain non-deadlocks may wait for innodb_lock_wait_timeout.

**Edit**

Since the transaction looks like

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ...;
compute some stuff
UPDATE ... (using that stuff);
COMMIT;
```

You need to add `FOR UPDATE` on the end of the `SELECT`.

Comment: i was using LOCK TABLES together with innoDB transactions, but thats not reason, reason is, i needed to make other (theoretical) concurrent transaction (or select on one specific table) wait, until the first transaction will finish. there is no another way, how to block access to some table than use LOCK TABLES.. Imagine i have table Invoices and need to generate custom unique id, before i insert row in this table. So i need to make select on this table, eg where year = 2005, it will return some id, and i will increase it and insert new row with unique invoice id, but, theoretically there

Comment: can be two concurrent threads which are at same moment doing the select (year=2005) to build the "unique" invoice id or number.. so if table is locked, no other concurrent thread can work with the table.. so thats why used lock tables. but on the end, i am not using lock tables, but rather insert, and if the insert fails (because  the invoice number is UNIQUE column, and because of theoretical concurrent thread), i will just generate again the invoice number, rather. but as i said, drawback of this method is, if the transaction in first thread will rollback, there will be hole in numbering.

Comment: Still no need for `LOCK TABLES`.  One thread `INSERTs` a row and calls `last_insert_id()`, which is specific to thread, to get unique `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.  Other thread does likewise; it _will_ get a different id.  Or...  If you are not using `AUTO_INCREMENT`, please provide details so I can explain why it, to, is not a problem.  You will need a `BEGIN` ... `COMMIT` around any combination of SQL statements that constitute a "transaction".

Comment: Hi Rick, yes you are right, in case of auto incremental ids, inserts are safe, however, althought here still is the classical autoincremental id, i am setting another column named "number", which has format like 1X-year-number. And before i make insert in the table, i need to generate correct unique number, and thats the story i posted above. Cheers

Comment: Please show use the set of SQL statements that make up this action.  We will advise on how to add `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` to make it 'safe' _and_ avoid _table_ locks.

Comment: I think FOR UPDATE statement will not fix the situation, that two threads will get same ids in same moment. FOR UPDATE only locks table for writting. There is no functionallity similar to LOCK TABLES for reading in innodb, i think.

Comment: (1) Thread A does `FOR UPDATE`; (2) Thread B tries to do `FOR UPDATE` but has to wait; (3) A does `UPDATE`; (4) Thread B can now complete the `FOR UPDATE` and `SELECT` returns the newly updated row, then it computes and decides to `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: Hi Rick, sorry for later answer. I tried it just now. It's strange, because i thought i tried it before yet and it didn't work, but now i see it probably works, just like you say. That means it does what it should do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after the [table_lock_timout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_lock_wait_timeout) variable which was introduced in MySQL 5.0.10 but subsequently [removed in 5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/mysql-nutshell.html). Unfortunately, the release notes don't specify an alternative to use, and I'm guessing that the general attitude is to switch over to using InnoDB transactions as @Rick James has stated in his answer.

I think that removing the variable was unhelpful. Others may regard this as a case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where we are trying to fix a symptom (deadlocks) by changing the timeout period of locking tables when really we should resolve the root cause by switching over to transactions instead. *I think there may still be cases where table locks are more suitable to the application than using transactions* and are perhaps a lot easier to comprehend, even if they are worse performing.

The nice thing about using `LOCK TABLES`, is that you can state the tables that you're queries are dependent upon before proceeding. With transactions, the locks are grabbed at the last possible moment and if they can't be fetched and time-out, you then need to check for this failure and roll back before trying everything all over again. It's simpler to have a 1 second timeout (minimum) on the lock tables query and keep retrying to get the lock(s) until you succeed and then proceeding with your queries before unlocking the tables. This logic is at no risk of deadlocks.

I believe the developer's attitude is summed up by the following excerpt from the [documetation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-locking.html):

> ...avoid using the LOCK TABLES statement, because it does not offer
>   any extra protection, but instead reduces concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to say the default timeout value; which is `50 Seconds` per [`MySQL Documentation`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) it says

> innodb_lock_wait_timeout  Default 50   The timeout in seconds an
>   InnoDB transaction may wait for a row lock before giving up. The
>   default value is 50 seconds

Comment: I believe this is for row lock, not table lock.

Comment: no i meant, how to set it. and as i said, i tried to change the value you are talking about, but it seems it has no effect. it is probably related to another locking (eg SELECT ... FOR UPDATE) locking, but thats not doing what i need. i needed to make concurrent transaction wait, before the another one finishes. but thank you anyway